# Ember JS with remote auth backend (XML response)

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, ember.js, cross-domain

Using Ember-Simple-Auth (custom authenticator) and `Ember.$.ajax()`

**Authentication procedure:**

1. Link to `authsite.com/login`, and log in there
2. If OK, external website redirects to `mysite.com/someroute?sid=xxx&uid=xxx`
3. I retrieve those parameters
4. I can get a big XML file with a lot of info by making a request to `authsite.com/check?sid=xxx&uid=xxx` if user is authenticated. Auth backend constraint: this request must come from the same IP as step 2.

---

I have a problem making this request because:

1. Not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
2. Not JSONP
3. Cannot enable CORS
4. Setting `crossDomain: true` and xhr credentials to true doesn't work either when doing `Ember.$.ajax()`

What are my options if I want to do everything in the front-end?

Comment: it sounds like you have no access to modify the auth service? the same IP constraint sounds like a blocker to me since the request to authenticate in ember will always come from the client's IP. can you build another auth service on the same IP that talks to the first one? bypassing the same IP constraint?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. But I do not know how to do that without touching some server-side code (I have none at the moment and would like to keep it that way).